# With iOS 7's new screenshot methods, one returns a UIImage without the status bar, one returns a UIView with it. How do I blur the status bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uiimage

I want to blur the whole screen *including* the status bar and then present a UIImageView on top of it, but it's proving difficult.

iOS 7's screenshot method `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` returns a UIImage that's really easy to blur and present, but doesn't include the status bar (at least by default), so it doesn't work as I'd like it to. The other `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`, returns a UIView *with* the status bar (yay!) but unfortunately as it's a UIView I don't know how to blur it.

Can I quickly convert a UIView to a UIImage to blur? Can the first method include the status bar somehow? Can I blur a UIView efficiently?

I'm just trying to blur the whole screen (including the status bar) to present an image on top of it. If I'm overlooking an additional way please feel free to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` on your app's window? The window /should/ contain the status bar. From there you obtain the image then apply whatever effect you want.

Comment: Why should the main window contain the status bar? The status bar is in a whole different window.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't include the status bar.

Comment: Call that method on the view returned by `- [UIScreen snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:]`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a UIView, you can do the following to convert it to an image:

```
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(YOUR_UIVIEW.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
//if it is retina display
            }
            else{
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(YOUR_UIVIEW.bounds.size);
//no retina display
            }
            [YOUR_UIVIEW.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

You can use *image for the image, or convert *imageData where ever you please.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, as it's [15x slower](http://f.cl.ly/items/323c000h013V2f3R2p3b/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-16%20at%2001.12.37%20.png) than just having an image be returned. Perfect world would be the 15x faster one with just a status bar.

Answer (score -1):

Why not call `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` on the result of `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`? That way you can get the status bar in the UIView (instead of its own UIWindow) and then create and modify the UIImage.

```
extension UIScreen {

    class func screenshotView() -> UIView {
        return mainScreen().snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
    }

    class func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        let view = screenshotView()

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size)
        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshot
    }

}
```